# How to rollback record modifications with ember-data-1.0.0-beta6

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With ember-data 0.0.14 transactions could be simply `.rollback()`. But now transactions are gone. Also gone are any details on how to cancel record modifications: we only have information on how to [persist records](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/)

How can modifications be rolled back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions are gone, but you can still call `rollback()` on a model.

For example, in an `ObjectController` you could have

```
actions: {
   discardChanges: function() {
      this.get('model').rollback();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. As a note for ember maintainers: it would be sensible to add that to the documentation.

Comment: To be fair it's [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback), although a bit hard to find.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't see it while migrating my app during this whole week :( I could swear there was a model lifecycle description in the old documentation.

Comment: Didn't try it yet, but I guess it will. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

For your information:
 Model.rollback() is RENAMED  to model.rollbackAttributes()
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3305

Comment: And this is the info currently available at the docs
 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes

Note that if applied to a new (unpersisted) record, it will delete it